# Phone number validation using JQuery & RegEx

Tags: jquery, regex

i am bit week in regex.i am trying to validate phone no by regex & jquery and it works when i am giving phone number like +4401634687222 or 3301634687222. basically phone number may look like below and those no are valid.

```
+44 (0) 1634 687222
+44(0)1634687222
4401634687222
25805487
```

here is my code for validation.

```
var regEx = '1?\W*([2-9][0-8][0-9])\W*([2-9][0-9]{2})\W*([0-9]{4})(\se?x?t?(\d*))?';
var val = jQuery.trim($("input[id*='txtEnqphone']").val())
if (!val.match(regEx)) {
    if ($('#Enquery_feed_loader').html() != '') {
        $('#Enquery_feed_loader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('#Enquery_feed_loader').html('<span>' + dialog_Msg.Invalid_Phone + '</span>');
        }).fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('#Enquery_feed_loader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('#Enquery_feed_loader').html('<span>' + dialog_Msg.Invalid_Phone + '</span>');
        }).fadeIn('slow');
    }

    $("input[id*='txtEnqphone']").focus()
    flag = false;
    return false;
}
```

so just change my regex expression as a result i can enter the above phone number. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
^\(?\d{3}\)?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
^[+][0-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

The above regex will **allow** following pattern :

**+974-584-5656 | +000-000-0000 | +323-343-3453**

And following will **not** be **allowed**.

**974-584-5656 | +974 000 0000**

**Edit :**

For above regex modification is : `^[0-9]\d{2} \d{3} \d{4}`

The other regex you can try out is :

```
^(1\s*[-\/\.]?)?(\((\d{3})\)|(\d{3}))\s*[-\/\.]?\s*(\d{3})\s*[-\/\.]?\s*(\d{4})\s*(([xX]|[eE][xX][tT])\.?\s*(\d+))*$
```

Allowed : 2405525009 | 1(240) 652-5009

Comment: people may give without + sign also and that should be allowed. so what to change in regex for that.plus sign should be optional. people may use or may not.

Comment: i want the phone no may or may not start with + sign.phone no may have - or () chanracter or may have space and length should be more than 6. can u please give me the exact regex for my requirement. thanks

Comment: you have to play a bit around this !!!